# AJAX request works fine but when I click the icon that is inside the button, I get a 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting a 500 internal server error ONLY when I click the thumbs-up icon that is inside the like button:

```
<button class="submit-btn like" id='{{ $image->id }}'>
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like
</button>
```

If I click anywhere else on the button, the AJAX request goes through and the like gets inserted in the database so the issue is definitely related to the icon.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
        var imageId = event.target.id;

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlLike,
            data: {
                imageId: imageId,
                _token: token
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            if ($('.like').hasClass('liked')) {
                $('.like').removeClass('liked');
                $('.like').html('<i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> Like');
            } else {
                $('.like').addClass('liked');
                $('.like').html('<i class="fas fa-check"></i> Liked');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, something you are sending to your backend is wrong. The backend can't understand what you are sending or doesn't know how to process it. Might want to ensure what you are sending and what your backend is seeing.

Comment: What happens server-side when you `post` `imageId` and `token`? There must be a relevant error entry in your error log server-side. Check that and update your question in order to get an appropriate answer.

Comment: I'm just guessing but could it be that some other event is attached to the inner <i>?

Comment: Did you actually mean `currentTarget`?  You might be dispatching from the `<i>` which doesn't have an `id`.

Comment: After changing target to currentTarget, I don't get the error anymore. I assume that I was trying to set the var imageId in JavaScript to the id of the <i> when I was clicking it which meant I was sending empty imageId to the back-end. Thanks. Feel free to post it as an answer so I can select it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because when you click the `i` within the `button` that's what `e.target` points to. In turn, that has no `id` attribute, so you're passing an empty property to your server side logic, which causes the 500 error.

To fix this, change `e.target` to `this` (or `e.currentTarget`), as it's guaranteed by jQuery to be the element you selected, not the child element which raised the event. Try this:

```js
$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
  var imageId = this.id;
  console.log(imageId);

  // your AJAX here...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="submit-btn like" id="{{ $image->id }}">
  <i class="far fa-thumbs-up">THUMBS UP</i> Like
</button>
```

Note in this example that anywhere you click on the button the reference to the element is the same.

Also, if the lack of a property in the request caused a 500 error I'd suggest implementing some stricter validation on your server side.